# Using job-template for multiple jobs with overrided params

Tags: jenkins, yaml, jenkins-job-builder

I need to extend the list of publishers for a single job in yamls. How can I do smth like that:

```
job-template:
   name: "template name"
   publishers:
      - slack:
         room: "#room-1"

project:
   name: "project name"
   jobs:
      - test_job_1:
         branch: master

      - test_job_2:
         branch: not_master
         publishers:
            - slack:
               room: "#room-2"
```

I mean, to extend publishers in `test_job_2`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the easiest way is to add variables

```
job-template:
   slack_rooms: "#room-1"
   name: "template name"
   publishers:
      - slack:
         room: "{slack_rooms}"

project:
   name: "project name"
   jobs:
     - test_job_1:
        branch: master

     - test_job_2:
        branch: not_master
        slack_rooms: "#room-1,#room-2"
```